# accordion messes up in IE6

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

Can someone please help me figure out why my accordion script at http://www.mincovlaw.com/services/copyright gets all messed up in IE6?

Unlike in more modern browsers, it triggers two onclick events if I click on "whether a work is protected by copyright", "whether a particular use of the work requires permission"...

I assume it has something to do with having an onclick on a `<li>` inside the `<ul>`, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT: Code:

```
<script>
    function treatlink(e) {
        if (!e)
              e = window.event;

            if (e.cancelBubble)
              e.cancelBubble = true;
            else
              e.stopPropagation();
    }

    function togglemore(z) {
        y=document.getElementById(z);
        w=document.getElementById('img'+z);
        if (y.style.display=="none") { 
            y.style.display="block"; 
            w.src='/images/icons/closemore1.png'
        } else { 
            y.style.display="none"; 
            w.src='/images/icons/openmore1.png'
        }
    }


</script>

    <ul class="dash">

        <li class='dash' onclick='togglemore("service_a"); return false;'>Legal opinions as to:
            <a href='#' onclick='return false;'><img id='imgservice_a' src='/images/icons/openmore1.png' style='vertical-align:text-top; padding-left:8px; border:0px; padding-right:5px; position:relative; top:7px;' title='Read More' alt='Read More'></a>
            <div id='service_a' style='display:none; width:600px;margin-left:50px;padding:6px;border:1px dotted #bbbbbb;'>Legal opinions may be provided in writing or as part of face-to-face, telephone or skype consultations.</div>
        </li>

        <ul class="dash">

        <li class='checkmark' onclick='togglemore("service01"); return false;'>whether a work is protected by copyright;
            <a href='#' onclick='return false;'><img id='imgservice01' src='/images/icons/openmore1.png' style='vertical-align:text-top; padding-left:8px; border:0px; padding-right:5px; position:relative; top:7px;' title='Read More' alt='Read More'></a>
            <div id='service01' style='display:none; width:600px;margin-left:50px;padding:6px;border:1px dotted #bbbbbb;'><p><i>Copyright Act</i> provides that copyright subsists in &ldquo;every original literary, dramatic, musical and artistic work&rdquo;. However, the scope of copyright protection is not indefinite.<p>It is of utmost importance to clearly understand if a particular result of creative activity is protected by copyright &ndash; whether you are planning to rely on that IP as your asset or whether you are planning to use someone else&rsquo;s work.</div>
        </li>


        <li class='checkmark' onclick='togglemore("service02"); return false;'>whether a particular use of the work requires permission;
            <a href='#' onclick='return false;'><img id='imgservice02' src='/images/icons/openmore1.png' style='vertical-align:text-top; padding-left:8px; border:0px; padding-right:5px; position:relative; top:7px;' title='Read More' alt='Read More'></a>
            <div id='service02' style='display:none; width:600px;margin-left:50px;padding:6px;border:1px dotted #bbbbbb;'><p>Even if a work is protected by copyright, not every single use of it requires permission from the copyright owner.<p>Some uses fall under the category of fair dealing, and some uses fall outside the legal definition of what &ldquo;use&rdquo; means under the <i>Copyright Act</i>.</div>
        </li>


        <li class='checkmark' onclick='togglemore("service03"); return false;'>whether a particular use of the work infringes copyright;
            <a href='#' onclick='return false;'><img id='imgservice03' src='/images/icons/openmore1.png' style='vertical-align:text-top; padding-left:8px; border:0px; padding-right:5px; position:relative; top:7px;' title='Read More' alt='Read More'></a>
            <div id='service03' style='display:none; width:600px;margin-left:50px;padding:6px;border:1px dotted #bbbbbb;'><p>Under the <i>Copyright Act</i>, it &ldquo;is an infringement of copyright for any person to do, without the consent of the owner of the copyright, anything that by this Act only the owner of the copyright has the right to do.&rdquo;<p>The question is whether a particular use falls under the scope of what only the owner of copyright can do and whether a particular use can be excused under the fair dealing provisions.</div>
        </li>

        </ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some relevant code (and maybe a JSFiddle example) here. With only an external link, the question will have no value to future readers once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: IE6? [(Almost) nobody uses that browser anymore.](http://www.getclicky.com/marketshare/global/web-browsers/internet-explorer/)

Comment: @You: Stats are fun and everything, but if you are developing an application for a specific market then that graph is all but useless. For example IE6 is still seen quite a lot in the diagnostic engineering world, it seems.

Comment: @Tomalak: Point taken, but this is quite obviously a page directed at the generic user, so I'd say the graph applies here.

Comment: My approach is simple. If it is possible to make it work in IE6 without having to compromise the way everything works in newer browsers, I'd much rather have it work in IE6, regardless of its market share..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE6 ignores closing `</li>` tags, so the inner `<ul>` you have on line 263 (which is positioned invalidly) is being interpreted as being inside the `<li>` above it, whereas in modern browsers it is interpreted as being a sibling of the `<li>`.

You should fix the invalidity by placing the inner `<ul>` inside an `<li>` of the outer `<ul>`.

Comment: I'm sure you identified the problem, but I'm not sure I understand your response as to how to fix it. Where do I need to place the `ul` instead?

Comment: inside each of the 3 `<li>`'s or do I add another global `<li>`?

Comment: Don't move or copy it. Just change the `<ul>` to `<li><ul>` and the `</ul>` to `</ul></li>`. You may need to adjust the styling to allow for the added `<li>`.